# How do I specify the full path of a file using Minim in Processing?

Tags: file, path, processing, minim

I am using Windows, and running Processing 3.

I downloaded a [french audiovisualizer](https://github.com/samuellapointe/ProcessingCubes), and it by default has a folder named "data" with a song.wav inside. When booting up the processing project it required me to make the project in its own folder, so I believe the location of the song.wav is different now.

So, I decided to do the reasonable thing and specify the full path of the song which changed the code from this:

```
  song = minim.loadFile("song.wav");
```

to

```
  song = minim.loadFile("C:\Users\*******\Downloads\ProcessingCubes-master\data\PulseWAV.wav");
```

(My user tag has been ommitted.)

But this returned the nasty error of:

```
processing.app.SketchException: Not expecting symbol 'U', which is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U.
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.preprocess(JavaBuild.java:376)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.preprocess(JavaBuild.java:155)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.build(JavaBuild.java:122)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaBuild.build(JavaBuild.java:104)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaMode.handleLaunch(JavaMode.java:122)
    at processing.mode.java.JavaEditor.lambda$0(JavaEditor.java:1099)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm not very familiar with processing, just decided to do it for this one project, so I don't know how to continue from here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash `\` character is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Escape characters let you use combinations like `"\n"` for newline or `"\t"` for tab.

Your error is telling you that `"\U"` is not a valid combination, so `"C:\Users..."` is not allowed.

To fix this, you need to *escape the escape character*. In other words, you need to use `"\\"` instead of `"\"`.

```
"C:\\Users\\*******\\Downloads\\ProcessingCubes-master\\data\\PulseWAV.wav"
```

This is a common problem with Windows file paths. In my experience you can also use forward slashes:

```
"C:/Users/*******/Downloads/ProcessingCubes-master/data/PulseWAV.wav"
```

By the way, it's generally a good idea to google any error messages you don't understand. I tried googling `"Not expecting symbol 'U', which is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U."` and got a couple results which look like they would have unblocked you.

Comment: Thank you for that, I did google that error, and when looking at it again afterwords, I realized that this was caused by the escape character, but still did not know how to solve it.